# iPhone app distribution build warning

Tags: iphone, distribution

I build my app with distribution profile. Every thing goes fine except one warning,

warning: 'The Validate Built Product build setting was not enabled when building for Distribution.'

I find it on Google but get nothing.

Is this warning affect my distribution build.?

Can some one explains what that warning means.?

I followed all steps mentioned at developer portal.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Shreya,

Please follow the instructions here:  http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/4/3/xcode-322-validate-built-product.html

This will be in Xcode under Build -> Project settings

Rob

Comment: Thank You Rob for your great help.